# How to find Scale of a song

Tags: python, matlab, fft, frequency

SCALE of the song - Scale of the song is determined from the given group of chords present in a signal.

Refer to http://songkeyfinder.com/ to find out the group of chords for different scales.

Scale of the song can also be determined from the given set of frequencies which occurs most in the signal.

I have written this code in MATLAB which shows the plot of frequencies with their occurrences.

```
[wave,freq]  = audioread('Our_song.wav');
dt  = 1/ freq;
Stoptime = 1;
t = (0:dt:Stoptime-dt);
n = length(wave)-1;
df = freq/n;
figure;
f = 0:freq/n:99999*freq/n;
ff=abs(fft(wave))/n;
fflength= length(ff);
ffpart=ff(1:100000);
plot(f,ffpart);
```

How can I store the first n most occurring frequencies of the signal?

Answer (score 3):

By applying an fft to the whole signal, you lose temporal information.
You may not be that familiar with audio processing, but it seems to that such exercise is fun to learn a bit the basics if you are curious about it.
The common time-frequency representation of a signal is the [STFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform), check out the Matlab help on spectrogram.

However, the STFT is not the best to highlight musical structure, you might want to represent the audio signal using chroma features. It will results in a matrix with 12 "bins" corresponding to the 12 notes of the chromatic scale.

An example of how to achieve this chroma analysis is described [here](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/matlab/chroma-ansyn/).
From the chroma representation you could try to identify the notes which are played along time.

However, this is no straightforward task. I would strongly advise to start working with a recording containing only one instrument. First, without any chords (e.g. melody on a piano), if you manage to get the sequence of notes correctly, try the same instrument with chords.
A mixture of different instruments would be more challenging.

Comment: Hey!
This seems to help. Thanks a lot.